# Why do styles dissapear after remove?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm facing this problem, when `tr` is clicked, the ids gets reordered but the `td` styles dissapears and I don't know why.

```js
$("tr").on("click", function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $(this).remove();
  parent.children("tr").each(function(i){
       $(this).attr('id', (i+1));
       $(this).html((i+1));
  });
});
```

```css
tr{
  color: #444;
  background: #ccc;
}
td{
  min-width: 125px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4">
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the `tr`'s contents with your call to `.html`, wiping out the `td` within it. You probably meant to be replacing the contents of that `td` instead:

```
$("tr").on("click", function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $(this).remove();
  parent.children("tr").each(function(i){
       $(this).attr('id', (i+1));
       $(this).find("td").html((i+1));
       //     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  });
});
```

Updated Snippet:

```js
$("tr").on("click", function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $(this).remove();
  parent.children("tr").each(function(i){
       $(this).attr('id', (i+1));
       $(this).find("td").html((i+1));
       //     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  });
});
```

```css
tr{
  color: #444;
  background: #ccc;
}
td{
  min-width: 125px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4">
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Side note: A couple of other thoughts:

- Instead of `parent.children()` you can use `siblings`:
- `$(this).attr("id", i+1)` is a very long way to write `this.id = i+1`. :-)
- No need to repeat the `i+1`

So:

```
$("tr").on("click", function() {
  var siblings = $(this).siblings();
  $(this).remove();
  siblings.each(function(i){
       ++i;
       this.id = i;
       $(this).find("td").html(i);
  });
});
```

```js
$("tr").on("click", function() {
  var siblings = $(this).siblings();
  $(this).remove();
  siblings.each(function(i){
       ++i;
       this.id = i;
       $(this).find("td").html(i);
  });
});
```

```css
tr{
  color: #444;
  background: #ccc;
}
td{
  min-width: 125px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4">
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the function is turning:

```
<tr id="1">
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

Into:

```
<tr id="1">
  1
</tr>
```

The `td` style isn't getting applied because there is no `td`.

```
$(this).html((i+1));
```

Should be

```
$(this).find('td').html((i+1));
```